# passing operator== to set in c++

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, operator-overloading, set

I want to have a `set<double> S;` and insert some doubles into it. but I want the set to consider `1.0000001 == 1.0000000` (comparing doubles using epsilon) (I mean if I insert both of the numbers to the set, set.size() should equal to one). I know how to pass the operator() (for comparing) to the set but I don't know how to pass the function:

```
const double eps = 1e-8;
bool operator==(double a, double b)
{
    return abs(a - b) < eps;
}
```

to the set.

P.S: Thanks to Sid. @Sid: I found out that: operator== is not used by std::set. Elements a and b are considered equal iff !(a < b) && !(b < a).

Comment: I am not a C++ specialist but I am pretty sure that you are expected to use a transitive relation as comparison for sets. Your `operator==`  is not transitive.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio it doesn't matter which of the two numbers are in the set. It is important that one of them is in the set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I initialize a std::set comparator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782702/how-do-i-initialize-a-stdset-comparator)

Comment: This definition of equality smells like trouble, as you are breaking the transitive property of the equality (if A==B and B==C then A==C). Take A=1, B=1+eps and C=1+2*eps, A==B, B==C, but A!=C. I wouldn't be surprised if this could break the implementation of the std::set in unpredictable ways.

Comment: You probably want fabs( ) instead of abs( ).  And  the comparison function of interest will be less().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the comparison function then why do you need operator== ? Take a look at the following thread.

[std::set with user defined type, how to ensure no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114856/stdset-with-user-defined-type-how-to-ensure-no-duplicates)

Look at [Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114867/559095).

Comment: see the P.S I have a question

Comment: Yes it's true. But you can control that behavior in your compare function. For example if a=1.0000000 and b=1.0000001 you can check if fabs(a-b) is less than 1e-6 (or whatever precision you want) then you return a false (that is neither is a less than b nor is b less than a) hence telling the <set> that a and b are considered equal.

Comment: That won't fulfill the requirements of the comparator function, since `!comp(k1, k2) && !comp(k2, k1)` won't define an equivalence relationship, and the relationship isn't transitive: `comp(k1, k2) && comp(k2, k3)` can return false even if `comp(k1, k3)` is true.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are right - this will break transitivity. Thinking of a better solution.

Comment: @Farzam  Here's an existing discussion on the topic. Farzam using the method I suggested may have pitfalls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816156/are-ieee-floats-valid-key-types-for-stdmap-and-stdset

Comment: Also, it would be useful to look at the discussion in this newsgroup on this very topic. Seems like this is a known and widely debated problem: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/f3439f6267f06250

Comment: Right now, there is no "answer with 12 upvotes." Please be more descriptive. Maybe you could say "the answer from Paul." In addition, you can link directly to the answer you mean; use the "link" item inside that answer to get the permalink for it; it will remain valid even when the vote counts change or if a user changes his or her user name.

Comment: @RobKennedy Was referring to the answer by Mehrdad Afshari on that thread. But link is really what I need. Here goes:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1114867/559095
Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I see. I've edited your answer to make that clear. What's odd is that Mehrdad's answer has not had 12 up votes in the time since you answered this question. (It has 11 now, with no down votes. And it hasn't been edited recently, either, which is the only way a prior up-voter could have rescinded a vote.)

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks for that. Well, then it was probably an error on my part. I guess my ++ operator is hyper-active today.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you can't, at least not that easily.   You
have to define a comparison operator which defines a strict weak
ordering.  If you have something like:

```
bool
cmpDouble( double lhs, double rhs )
{
    return abs( lhs - rhs ) < eps
        ? false
        : lhs < rhs;
}
```

then `! (a < b) && ! (b < a)` doesn't define an equivalence
relationship, so a major requirement isn't met.

It's possible to use something like:

```
bool
cmpDouble( double lhs, double rhs )
{
    double iLhs;
    modf( 1e8 * lhs, &iLhs );
    double iRhs;
    modf( 1e8 * rhs, &iRhs );
    return iLhs < iRhs;
}
```

But frankly, I suspect that if the source of your doubles requires this
sort of thing, they probably aren't appropriate for storing in a `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the link provided by @Sid, it seems that (however well- or ill-advised it is), you can do this by defining your comparison operators as follows:

```
const double eps = 1e-8;
bool less_than(double a, double b)
{
    return a < b - eps;
}

bool greater_than(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b + eps;
}
```

Comment: Which doesn't define an equivalence relationship, and isn't transitive, so it doesn't define a strict weak ordering.  (Which means that using it as a comparison function for `std::set<double>` is undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quantize your doubles **before** inserting them into the set.

If you consider all numbers in the range 1.0000000 <= x < 1.0000002 to be identical, simply replace all numbers in this range by 1.0000000 **before** inserting them into the set.  Likewise for 1.0000002 <= x < 1.0000004 etc.

This approach avoids all issues with comparison operators and transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad idea. Consider the case of the numbers `1.0000000`, `1.0000001`, `1.0000002`. If you insert `1.0000001` first then neither of the other numbers would be allowed to be added to the set. If you add `1.0000000` or `1.0000002` first then the other could be added later.

Additionally, `set` uses `operator<` to define its relationship, NOT equality. I can't see a way of writing a strict weak ordering that relies on an epsilon, it's just not going to result in a properly sorted container. The container relies *just* on `operator<` or other comparison and there's no way of specifying an equality operation.

Better is to just use the normal `<` comparison and do post-processing after you've built the set to clean up the elements you don't want anymore. If you give us more information about the *real* problem you're trying to solve we may be able to help.

Comment: You can always define a set of discrete ranges using `modf` (or probably other things as well), and then use a characteristic element in each range for the comparison.  But your last suggestion is probably better.

Answer (score -1):

```
const double eps = 1e-8;
bool compare(double a, double b)
{
    return (abs(a - b) > eps) ? (a < b) : false;
}

set<int,bool(*)(double,double)> set (compare);
```

---

```
struct Compare
{
    bool operator()(double a, double b) const
    {
        return (abs(a - b) > eps) ? (a < b) : false;
    }
};

set<int,Compare> set;
```

Comment: Ahm, shouldn't the comparison function define a "less than" relationship, rather than "is equal to"?

Comment: but this passes operator<, I want to pass operator==.

Comment: @Farzam `std::set` orders its elements using an ordering relationship, `std::less` by default.  It does not test for equality, but counts on `!cmp(lhs, rhs) && !cmp(rhs, lhs)` defining an equivalence relation.  (Which the proposed function doesn't.)